# How does a plasma react to a non-uniform, oscillating magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, plasma-physics

The ponderomotive force tells me that if I apply some non-uniform oscillating acceleration field $\ddot{x} = g(x) cos (\omega t)$ where $g(x)$ is the strength of the field as a function of location and $cos(\omega t)$ describes high frequency oscillations, it will result in some motion towards decreasing $g(x)$:

$\ddot{x}_0 = - \frac{1}{4 \omega^2}\frac{d}{dx}[g(x)^2]$

This makes sense intuitively and [the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponderomotive_force) explains the phenomenon of the ponderomotive force well.

But supposing now that I have some plasma with known properties that is subject to a non-uniform oscillating magnetic field (as is the case in the [Electrodeless Plasma Thruster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrodeless_plasma_thruster)), what is the function that describes the net force exerted on the plasma?

What's confusing me is that I cannot simply ask "what's the motion of the plasma under a magnetic field" and then derive the ponderomotive effect myself, because a plasma is electrically neutral so presumably that wouldn't get me very far.

Comment: Have you tried looking at Faraday's law?

Comment: No I haven't, but thanks for the tip - I'll have a look.